# Tomcat shared loader not taken into account

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, shared, loader

To precise the context, I am using Eclipse with its workspace metadata for my **Tomcat 7**'s configuration.

I have this line in my catalina.properties :

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/shared/conf
```

Which, should load all the files contained in ${catalina.home}/shared/conf **before** all the files contained in my web application (*WEB-INF/classes*).

But this is not what I observe, the files contained in my application always override those in my shared loader (ie. *log4j.xml*, etc.).

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Tomcat 4.1 hasn't been supported for over 4 years.

Second, you haven't read the page correctly. Look at the end of the "Class Loader Definitions" section where the search order is explicitly described.

If you want to change the delegation order then look at the `delegate` attribute of the Loader element. This is supported in all Tomcat versions from 4.1.x to 8.0.x.

Comment: Indeed my link was not relevant. This is the good one: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html. I can see no shared loader so I assume that I was getting wrong on this. I will edit my post to precise the version of my tomcat.

Comment: The shared loader is still supported but just disabled by default. Look in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties to re-enable it.

Comment: From what I read, it seems that adding the line mentioned in my question post is sufficient to activate it. I even tried to put it in the common loader without any effect. But I found an interesting point in the doc "When a request to load a class from the web application's WebappX class loader is processed, this class loader will look in the local repositories first, instead of delegating before looking."

Comment: Again, look at the delegate attribute of the Loader element if you want to change the delegation order.

Comment: Indeed, adding `<Loader delegate="true" />` in my **context.xml** solves the problem. Thanks Mark.